# When importing, find and replace the duplicate, or if there is no duplicate, paste at the bottom of the data set

Tags: database, if-statement, google-sheets, search, replace

I am attempting to compile a Database with financial information. To do this I need to import new data for each stock 'ticker' into the Database with a script that searches for the last empty row and pastes the data there.

However, If new data is available for a stock, I would like to paste it over the old in the Database - to avoid duplicates. And if there is no duplicates to continue with the original script to paste it at the next available row.

I think I would just need to tweak my current script to add a **Find and Replace** for any matches of **API ImporterTest!C2** and and tickers in Column **DatabaseTest!H:H** and if there is to paste the ranges in the script below over it, and an IF function for if there is no match to continue with the original script.

Here is the script I have been working with so far:

```
//set spreadsheet and sheets
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const importerSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API ImporterTest');
  const databaseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DatabaseTest');

//cash flow
  const lastRowColumnValuesCash = databaseSheet.getRange("G:G").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexCash = lastRowColumnValuesCash.length - lastRowColumnValuesCash.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//income statement
  const lastRowColumnValuesIncome = databaseSheet.getRange("AT:AT").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexIncome = lastRowColumnValuesIncome.length - lastRowColumnValuesIncome.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//balance sheet
  const lastRowColumnValuesBalance = databaseSheet.getRange("CC:CC").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexBalance = lastRowColumnValuesBalance.length - lastRowColumnValuesBalance.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//fundamentals
  const lastRowColumnValuesFund = databaseSheet.getRange("DY:DY").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexFund = lastRowColumnValuesFund.length - lastRowColumnValuesFund.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//keymetrics
  const lastRowColumnValuesMet = databaseSheet.getRange("GE:GE").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexMet = lastRowColumnValuesMet.length - lastRowColumnValuesMet.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//profile
  const lastRowColumnValuesProf = databaseSheet.getRange("IN:IN").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexProf = lastRowColumnValuesProf.length - lastRowColumnValuesProf.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');

//run
  if (databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 > databaseSheet.getMaxRows())
    databaseSheet.insertRowsAfter(databaseSheet.getMaxRows(),
      databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 - databaseSheet.getMaxRows()
    )
    importerSheet
    .getRange('F3:J40')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`G${lastRowIndexCash + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
  importerSheet
    .getRange('S3:W36')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`AT${lastRowIndexIncome + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
  importerSheet
    .getRange('AF3:AJ49')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`CC${lastRowIndexBalance + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true 
      );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('AS3:AW59')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`DY${lastRowIndexFund + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('BF3:BJ62')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`GE${lastRowIndexMet + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('BS3:BW36')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`IN${lastRowIndexProf + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
};
```

Here is a functional Test Sheet to test it on with example solutions (to produce a new dataset to test, change the cell 'C2' in 'API Importer Test' to another ticker, FB, AAPL, GME for example and hit import.)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UPAz7ku_AILB9aDvKCVyClvBh_5XskGPgGh0w784PR4/edit?usp=sharing

[An Example of the 2 Solutions - Note this sheet was for visualization of the logic only, so the current script would not work on these cells.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFu2G.png)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already know how to import the data but you need help checking for duplicates and overwriting instead of appending to empty rows if the duplicate is found? What counts as a duplicate, what column/s should be checked? Just the `ticker`? (in the spreadsheet you provided, that would be `General Motors Company`).

Comment: That is correct! Yep just the ticker is the criteria for duplicates, the cell `"API ImporterTest!F4"` and the `Column H in "DatabaseTest"` would be best to check for matches.

Comment: What's the reason for retrieving so many `lastRow` indexes in the `database` sheet? Shouldn't you add all the data to the same rows?

Comment: I modified the original script to import several ranges which are organised slightly apart in the database. I could probably streamline this in the future to what you are suggesting, but I would have to reorganize the database sheet. Also a possibility that did not need to do that in the first place haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

From my perspective, it doesn't make sense to retrieve so many `lastRow` indexes. This is the index in the sheet `Database` where data should be written if no duplicate `ticker` is found, and all these `lastRow` indexes should be the same. And at least in the example you provided, that is the case, all these indexes coincide.

Taking that into account, I'd do the following:

- Check the last row for column `G` (since I guess the date will always be populated if the row is populated).
- Retrieve the value from `API ImporterTest!B3`, corresponding to the imported ticker.
- Retrieve all current `tickers` in `Database`, currently in `C3`, filtering empty rows with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- Check if the ticker to be imported is in current tickers and, if that's the case, what index it is located. You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for that.
- Retrieve the `rowIndex` where to write the data to, depending on the index from previous step is `-1` or not (duplicate found), and taking into account that data start at row 3 and there are 5 merged cells everytime, so 4 out of 5 values was empty and so filtered out. Because of this, `rowIndex` should be `index * 5 + 3` if a duplicate was found. I used a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to do that in the sample below: `const rowIndex = index !== -1 ? index * 5 + 3 : lastRowIndexCash + 1;`
- Copy all the different ranges to the same `rowIndex`, since you want to write all data to the same rows.

#### Code sample:

```
const moveValuesOnly = () => {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const importerSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API ImporterTest');
  const databaseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DatabaseTest');
  const lastRowColumnValuesCash = databaseSheet.getRange("G:G").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexCash = lastRowColumnValuesCash.length - lastRowColumnValuesCash.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
  const importerTicker = importerSheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  const tickers = databaseSheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const index = tickers.indexOf(importerTicker);
  const rowIndex = index !== -1 ? index * 5 + 3 : lastRowIndexCash + 1;
  console.log(rowIndex)
  if (databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 > databaseSheet.getMaxRows()) {
    databaseSheet.insertRowsAfter(databaseSheet.getMaxRows(),databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 - databaseSheet.getMaxRows());
  };
  importerSheet.getRange('F3:J40').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`G${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true
  );
  importerSheet.getRange('S3:W36').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`AT${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true
  );
  importerSheet.getRange('AF3:AJ49').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`CC${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true 
    );
  importerSheet.getRange('AS3:AW59').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`DY${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true
  );
  importerSheet.getRange('BF3:BJ62').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`GE${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true
  );
  importerSheet.getRange('BS3:BW36').copyTo(
    databaseSheet.getRange(`IN${rowIndex}`),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
    true
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort so far. I understand the process so much more myself now.
However, I have copied your script into the Test file with no such luck, I can't see any evidence of anything being pasted. I tried it with both a duplicate ticker and a new entry. Was there a step I needed to do before pasting your solution before it worked?

Comment: @PeterMeloche My bad, I had a typo when copying my script to the answer (the `if` block should only include `insertRowsAfter`, and not the `copyTo` actions). I updated the script in my answer, it should be working now. Also, the `ticker` formulas in column C are not currently getting copied by the script, you can just drag down the formula instead. It could be added to the script if you think that's preferrable though. Let me know if that works for you now.

Comment: That is it perfectly working! Massive help, thank you so much. Saved me weeks. I think I'm happy to drag the formula down for now, thanks again,